# Rails: how to make an action redirect to different path depends on where it come from

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Model

> order has_many materials
>  material belongs_to order

when I update from material edit page. In material controller

```
def update
 ...
 redirect_to materials_path

end
```

I also want add a form in order's index page to update several material's attributes, when I update from index page I want it redirect to `index_path` in the same material update action. How to make an action redirect to different path dependes on where it comes from or any other condition? `redirect_to(:back)` not suit my problem.

Comment: You can add a `param` in form and check for the value in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `request.referer` and ruby's module `URI` to achieve that.

```
case URI(request.referer).path
when '/index'
  redirect_to index_path
...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can use hidden field to pass a action name like
`<%= hidden_field_tag :action_name, 'index' %>`
use it like

```
if params[:action_name] == 'index'
  redirect_to index_path
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution in another situation, works well for me.